# Canvas widget saying not defined when attempting to config it in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm having an issue, whenever I open the shop window, click the Attack Up 1 button, when the command it's attached to runs, it says that the attackUp1 variable is not defined even though it is set to be the widget. Have a peak at my code:

```
#opens shop canvas where you buy upgrades
def shop():
    global shop
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Shop")
    shop = Canvas (root, width = 150, height = 400, bg = "blue")
    shop.pack()
    attackUp1 = shop.create_window(77, 50, window = Button(shop, text = "Attack Up 1\n20 coins", font = ("calibri" , 20), command = attackIncreaser1))
    #attackUp2 = shop.create_window(77, 100, window = Button(shop, text = "Attack Up 2\n60 coins", font = ("calibri" , 20), command = shoot))

#runs when someone buys the attackUp1 upgrade and changes their stats or says that they don't have enough coins
def attackIncreaser1():
    global attack
    global attackPower
    global coins
    global shop
    global attackUp1

    if coins < attackUp1Price:
        attackUp1.config(text="Not enough coins")
    elif coins >= attackUp1Price:            
        attackPower = attackPower + 1
        attackUp1.config(text="")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        attackUp1.config(text="Attack Up 1\n20 coins")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does not run, which means I'll have to guess what is missing and add it to be able to debug. So my comments may be irrelevant...

I would not recommend creating the root window inside a function.

The variable `attackUp1` is created inside the function `shop()` which makes it local. When the function exits it is garbage collected.

The variable `attackUp1` is of type `int`. That is the nature of canvas objects. If you want to change the button text you'll need to save a reference to the button.

**Update**
As I look at this code again, wondering about why you would create an instance of `Tk()` inside a function, it seems to me you may be opening a new window. If this is the case you should use `Toplevel()` instead. It's not a good idea to have more than one root window: [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged/48045508#48045508)

As for passing the button reference, this may work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Shop")

def shop():
    global attackButton
    shop = Canvas (root, width = 150, height = 100, bg = "blue")
    shop.pack()
    attackButton = Button(shop, text="Attack Up 1\n20 coins",
                          command=attackIncreaser1)
    attackUp1 = shop.create_window(77, 50, window=attackButton)

def attackIncreaser1():
    attackButton.config(text="Not enough coins")

shop()

root.mainloop()
```